# Printing out Matrix values in OPENCV does not work

Tags: opencv

I started working with OPENCV and I firstly test some basic
commands. At the moment I try to print out a particular value of a jpg image. I already read several posts and constructed the following C++ program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()  //(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat image;
    image = imread("Desert.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);
    cout << image.at<Vec3b>(1, 1)[0] << std::endl;
    cout << image.at<Vec3b>(1,1) << std::endl;
    image.at<Vec3b>(1, 1)[0] = 10;
    cout << image.at<Vec3b>(1, 1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output in the terminal is

```
▒
[205, 123, 51]  
[10, 123, 51]
```

So I get a strange value when printing out the first channel of pixel (1,1). Contrary to that I can print all three at once. I can even change the value of pixel (1,1) in channel 1 using the same syntax.

I use visual Studio and Vesion 3.4.1 of OPENCV. Any suggestions or comments why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is printing a value that looks bad, but it is actually correct.

The type **Vec3b** is a vector with **3 byte entries**, where those bytes are stored as unsigned char values to represent the **0 -> 255** color range. You are seeing the byte value of 205 in the console.

The Vec3b object most likely has the << overridden to deal with printing out the values for the user to read.

Try type casting the byte to an int to see the value:

```
cout << (int)image.at<Vec3b>(1, 1)[0] << std::endl;
```